# Markdown heading type priority

Tags: markdown

## Here is a title

## Here is a title in another format

### Here is a heading

### Here is a heading in another format

## # What is this?

### ## And what is this?

Source...

```
Here is a title
===

# Here is a title in another format

Here is a heading
---

## Here is a heading in another format

# What is this?
===

## And what is this?
---
```

I can see how markdown is rendered, but I want to know if there is a rule in the spec that gives priority to one form of heading over the other, and how to handle text using both forms at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal spec for Markdown anywhere (only many different implementations); Jeff Atwood even [proposed that a Markdown standard should be formalized](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/10/the-future-of-markdown.html), but as of now, there has still not been a spec proposed. I assume then that the Stack Overflow implementation (and perhaps others as well) simply chooses to give priority to the headers written with underlines.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not very "scientific" because you never tested what would happen to mix `<h1>` hash with a `<h2>` underline, and reverse.

Of course this is going to differ across implementations, but here is the Kramdown test

```
$ cat foo.md
# mix h1 hash with h2 underline
----------------------------

## mix h1 underline with h2 hash
=============================
```

```htm
$ kramdown foo.md
<h1 id="mix-h1-hash-with-h2-underline">mix h1 hash with h2 underline</h1>
<hr />

<h2 id="mix-h1-underline-with-h2-hash">mix h1 underline with h2 hash</h2>
<p>=============================</p>
```